Getting 404 Not Found while retrieving an online meeting by meeting ID
Please find error faced in Postman
I want to retrieve meeting information via meeting ID . The meeting ID is provided in the response object when creating an onlineMeeting. I have passed this meeting id as following format :
"GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/81d9-4adb-bfc2-8f2a442e4642/onlineMeetings/MSpkYzE3Njc0Yy04MWQ5LYRhZGItYmZiMi04ZdFpHRTNaR1F6WGhyBWFkLnYy". But getting response as "404 Not Found". Please assist me in resolving this issue.
Thankyou.
I tried some endpoint URL's from microsoft Graph and their documentation, but no luck!.I was able to schedule and setup meeting, view my mails via API's.

You can use the following request to get the OnlineMeeting resource:
GET /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl eq '{joinWebUrl}'. Response to this API call will give you the correct Graph OnlineMeetingId
